# Is there something like Jquery memory or cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, memory

I've wrote a Script with jQuery for 360deg product preview. It works just fine. But if I "play" with it for a long time (dragging, zooming in, zooming out etc.) it becames slower and slower. If I'm dragging mouse slowly it works ok, but it freezes on fast mousemoves. After page reload it works again fine for several minutes and then become slower.

What can cause such behaviour? Is there something like jQuery memory that becomes full?

Per request, some parts of code:

Loading images:

```
$.getJSON("load.php", {dir: 'images/'}, function(output) {
var imagelist = jQuery.makeArray(output.imagelist);
var zoomlist = jQuery.makeArray(output.zoomlist);
var cache = [];

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        var im = $("<img>").attr("src",this);
        cache.push(im);
        image.attr('src', this);
    });
}
preload(imagelist);
```

Rotation part

```
holder.mousedown(function(e){
    var enterPosition = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    isDown = true;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(isDown && !isZoom){
            var cursorPosition = e.pageX - contOffset.left;
            var xOffset = cursorPosition - enterPosition;
            var step = Math.round(contWidth/countFrames);
            var frameOffset = Math.round(xOffset/step);
            var cycles = Math.abs(Math.floor((frameOffset+startFrame)/countFrames));

            currentFrame = startFrame + frameOffset;
            if(currentFrame >= countFrames){
                currentFrame = currentFrame - countFrames*cycles;
            }       
            if(currentFrame < 0){
                currentFrame = countFrames*cycles + currentFrame;
            }

            image.attr('src', imagelist[currentFrame]);
            $('#info').html(currentFrame);      
            var corner = Math.floor(360/countFrames);                       
            var degrees = corner*currentFrame;                              
            var radians=degrees*Math.PI/180;
            var sine=Math.sin(radians);
            var cose=Math.cos(radians);
            var poinx = rotCenter+rotRadius*sine*-1;
            var poiny = rotCenter+rotRadius*cose
            $('#pointer').css('left',poinx);
            $('#pointer').css('top',poiny);
        };
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        isDown = false;
        startFrame = currentFrame;
    });
});
```

Zooming part

```
$('#zoom').click(function(e){
    var isZoom = true;

    var offset = holder.offset();
    var startXpos = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var startYpos = e.pageY - offset.top;
    var zoomImg = new Image();

    zoomImg.onload = function() {
        zoomHeight = zoomImg.height;
        zoomWidth = zoomImg.width;

        var leftOverflow = (zoomWidth - contWidth)/-2;
        var topOverflow = (zoomHeight - contHeight)/-2;

        image.attr('src', zoomlist[currentFrame]);
        image.css('left', leftOverflow);
        image.css('top', topOverflow);
        $('#round').fadeOut();
        $('#zoom').fadeOut();           
        holder.addClass('zoomout');
        holder.mousemove(function(e){
            if(isZoom){
                var currentXpos = e.pageX - offset.left;
                var currentYpos = e.pageY - offset.top;

                var xlimit = (zoomWidth-contWidth)*-1;
                var ylimit = (zoomHeight-contHeight)*-1;



                var xSpeedCoeff = Math.floor(zoomWidth/contWidth);
                var ySpeedCoeff = Math.floor(zoomHeight/contHeight);
                var moveLeft = startXpos - currentXpos;
                var moveTop = startYpos - currentYpos;
                var leftOffset = leftOverflow + moveLeft*xSpeedCoeff;
                var topOffset = topOverflow + moveTop*ySpeedCoeff;
                var hMoveLock = false;
                var vMoveLock = false;


                if(leftOffset >= 0){
                    hMoveLock = true;
                    startXpos = startXpos - leftOffset;
                } 
                if(leftOffset <= xlimit){
                    hMoveLock = true;
                    startXpos = startXpos - leftOffset + xlimit;    
                }

                if(topOffset >= 0){
                    vMoveLock = true;
                    startYpos = startYpos - topOffset;
                } 
                if(topOffset <= ylimit){
                    vMoveLock = true;
                    startYpos = startYpos - topOffset + ylimit; 
                }

                if(!hMoveLock) {
                    image.css('left', leftOffset);
                }
                if(!vMoveLock) {
                    image.css('top', topOffset);
                }

                holder.mousedown(function(){

                    image.attr('src', imagelist[currentFrame]);
                    image.css('left', 0);
                    image.css('top', 0);
                    $('#round').fadeIn();
                    $('#zoom').fadeIn();            
                    holder.removeClass('zoomout');
                    pan = false;
                    isZoom = false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
    zoomImg.src = zoomlist[currentFrame];
});
```

I know, the code is not clear, and as it here now, I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Ok, actually I wanted to put the code on jsfiddle, but it loads images via JSON request and php => it wont work on jsfiddle...

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the posted code.

Comment: So, i've solved the problem. I had to move holder.mousedown(function(){ outside the holder.on('mousemove.dragpan', (function(e){ in zooming foonction. I also used namespaces to unbind events. Thank you guys for your tipps, was very helpful!

Comment: `@Sobakinet`: If none of the answers below is acceptable but you've solved the problem, please post the solution as an answer and then (when the system lets you) accept it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The both answers did really help to solve the problem. I don't think i have a moral right to accept my soluthion, that is fully based on your tipps and advices. I'm not very familiar with StackOverflow - do I really need to accept one of the answers? Another problem, that the part of code, that was causing a problem was removed from my question post by editor...

Comment: `@Sobakinet`: *"...do I really need to accept one of the answers..."* No. But if you found a solution, and rather than it being primarily one answer or the other, it was both plus your own insight, the best thing is to post your solution as an answer and accept it. It's all about having good answers, no one will (or at least, should) be offended. :-) *"...the part of code, that was causing a problem was removed from my question post by editor"* That was completely inappropriate of him (presumably a mistake, the rest of his edit was to make the code more readable). I've restored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was caused by the zoom function. What i did to solve it:

I have moved this part

```
holder.mousedown(function(){
   image.attr('src', imagelist[currentFrame]);
   image.css('left', 0);
   image.css('top', 0);
   $('#round').fadeIn();
   $('#zoom').fadeIn();            
   holder.removeClass('zoomout');
   pan = false;
   isZoom = false;
});
```

outside of

```
holder.mousemove(function(e){
   if(isZoom){
```

I've used namespaces to unbind mouse events.

```
holder.on('mousemove.dragpan', (function(e){
}));

holder.mousedown(function(){
   holder.off('mousemove.dragpan');
});
```

Thx again for all the tipps!

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of reasons this might happen, <s>it's impossible to say without seeing the code</s> *see below for an update now that you've posted the code*:

A couple of possibilities off the top of my head:

1. Yes, you *could* be allocating lots of objects and then either not releasing them, or the garbage collector is being slow.
2. You could be inadvertently re-attaching event handlers over and over, and so the events (which end up triggering all attached handlers) slow down because of the number of (redundant) handlers attached.

---

**Update** after you posted your code:

It's #2, this is the offending code (it may not be the *only* offending code):

```
holder.mousedown(function(e){
    var enterPosition = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    isDown = true;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        // ...
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        // ...
    });
});
```

What you're doing there is when the `mousedown` event fires on the `holder` element(s), you're *adding* a new handler for `mousemove` and `mouseup` to the document, on top of any handlers that are already there. So every mousedown introduces a new handler to the chain. Since `mousemove` happens a **lot**, that ever-increasing chain of handlers gets called a **lot**.

You should either only be attaching the `mousemove` and `mouseup` handlers *once*, not on every `mousedown`, or you should be sure to *remove* them on `mouseup`. (The latter will require that you don't use anonymous functions as you are currently, because you need to pass the **same** function reference into `unbind` that you passed [indirectly] into `bind`. **Edit**: Or you can use jQuery's "namespaced" event stuff.)

---

FWIW, this should get you started on the attach-it-once version:

```
(function() {   // Scoping function so isDown and enterPosition aren't globals
    var isDown = false,
        enterPosition;

    // I don't know where `holder` or `startFrame` come from, but presumably you do

    // Hook up mousedown on holder
    holder.mousedown(function(e){
        enterPosition = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        isDown = true;
    });

    // Hook up mousemove on document (just once)
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        // Flag controls whether we do anything
        if(isDown && !isZoom){
            var cursorPosition = e.pageX - contOffset.left;
            var xOffset = cursorPosition - enterPosition;
            var step = Math.round(contWidth/countFrames);
            var frameOffset = Math.round(xOffset/step);
            var cycles = Math.abs(Math.floor((frameOffset+startFrame)/countFrames));

            currentFrame = startFrame + frameOffset;
            if(currentFrame >= countFrames){
                currentFrame = currentFrame - countFrames*cycles;
            }       
            if(currentFrame < 0){
                currentFrame = countFrames*cycles + currentFrame;
            }

            image.attr('src', imagelist[currentFrame]);
            $('#info').html(currentFrame);      
            var corner = Math.floor(360/countFrames);                       
            var degrees = corner*currentFrame;                              
            var radians=degrees*Math.PI/180;
            var sine=Math.sin(radians);
            var cose=Math.cos(radians);
            var poinx = rotCenter+rotRadius*sine*-1;
            var poiny = rotCenter+rotRadius*cose
            $('#pointer').css('left',poinx);
            $('#pointer').css('top',poiny);
        };
    });

    // Hook mouseup on document (just once)
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        isDown = false;
        startFrame = currentFrame;
    });
})();
```

If your code is already within a scoping function, you don't need the new one I introduced.

Comment: Beat me to it. Yeah, that'd be my guess as well... without example code. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to understand it now ) The problem is that there is a holder element on the page. If user clicks it and then drags the mouse the animation must begin. But it must still run if user drags the mouse outside the holder element. Thats why i have $(document).mousemove inside holder.mousedown(. So i must unbind the holder.musedown function on document.mouseup event... will try to figure it out

Comment: @Sobakinet: You don't necessarily have to unbind, the other alternative is to bind once and use the flag you already have. See my update for a sketch of how that might work.

Comment: hm... it does not seem to help much. Can you please look hear http://dopeless.net/360/ the problem seems to start after zoom in and zoom outs.

Comment: @Sobakinet: Sorry, can't do that right now. I took a quick look, and somewhat off-topic, but if you use consistent, clear code indentation, it helps a **lot** -- for you, and for anyone who may need to read your code. The indentation of the code in the question, and in that link, is all over the place. Very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cache - you can access it with `$.cache`. And as T.J. Crowder said - it's most likely cause of you aren't cleaning up after yourself properly.

Do a `Object.keys($.cache).length;` in your console to check the size of cache - play for a while and check again to confirm that the cache grows to confirm jquery based leaks

and you are leaking cause on mouseup you are not unbinding your mouseup and mmousemove events

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(document).unbind('mouseup').unbind('mousemove');
    isDown = false;
    startFrame = currentFrame;
});
```

this should help a lot

Problem was that basically every time you were pressing mouse down you were binding mousemove and mouseup again and again so after clicking few times all the computation was multiplied by amount of times you've pressed mouse down. You could also namespace the mousemove and mouseup events to unbind by namespace rather then two events separately.

Also caching variables might help a bit - especially with this kind of heavy operations - mousemove fires a lot

edit:

to remove events with anonymous functions use namespaces

```
var doc = $(document);

doc.bind('mousedown', function(e) {

    doc.bind('mousemove.namespace', function(e) { ... });

    doc.bind('mouseup.namespace', function(e) {

        doc.unbind('.namespace');

        // do whatever else you need to do on mouseup
    });
});
```

just change namespace to whatever fits you best! Check jQuery docs for more info on namespaced events http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

apart of that if you don't pass any function to the event type you want to unbind it will unbind all the events of given type regardless of its namespace or if it was named function or anonymous one

Comment: Thx for an answer. T.J. Crowder wrote above, that it will not work with anonymus functions. But your solution still has anonymus functions?

Comment: check the edit to my answer - i've added solution with namespaces at the bottom which works with anonymous functions perfectly fine

Comment: @Sobakinet: Tom's quite right, if you use namespaces, you can unbind your handlers without having a reference to the actual function you originally bound. It's a very useful technique I keep forgetting about. :-)

Comment: thx again, i'll try it out too. You can take a look at example i've posted in a comment to a post from T.J. Crowder if you want to )

Comment: nice demo :) try to do it the way i told in the edit and it will work perfectly fine - the problem you are seeing is because of the not unbound mousemove + mouseup